# Drawing created by incompatible version - Save will be prevented || Design Automation API

Tags: autocad, autodesk, autocad-plugin, autodesk-designautomation, autocad-scripts

We created a autocad plugin, that draws a border around the object present in dwg file.
It works fine for all the created using autocad.

We have a file created with autocad mechanical 2022, for which design automation gives error
" Drawing created by incompatible version - Save will be prevented "
[Error Report Url](https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/YR4rlmfrF0a3Z6BRSxcxD5GW652EKPut/93a1af5b8e724d55a63bf15e5baa8a70/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=4620&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEE4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIEvFXo0LmzYkiG7LbSuPJfsC4lJ21zTJBrueJh1MGLMjAiEA%2BDfFi4sU2ibZ41nocrhJ4ZlhjTLscoSbmOdaYNqIV34qiQMI5%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDBJqeWosSPjCNyERbSrdAtqONMPDsuoKk%2B7OJnoWpA1NPlvj3a1nlLrnklaN8v1YEwQWPzvAD8wrUGV0AizksnMmpWsmAFF7Ngyj71bfXBY8bP31BlOKKcamSZ%2BeATVPiyVNwPL96kIKPa8B14W7lUj1vcpcfMtc7ZLZyB1S5xDzqUFVQ51hOG7PiPwfDQxaGteH9EzmqXIeHBVF6FvddZv7YBwf2uQ5UTNXXPMwoNb5Lh8IAB73ocrDd%2FoAmlKgKNygvFtsIeajEXLbMvmOXszTx5Nb4pMy8NPcqd5domDE8dBH9ySyVHLi5n%2FydEaRufEejLi7jy%2FFzD%2FVqpqIrw7ClHL2Mpr3RLu6iOEPMBwkzBkwLm663Qu%2FMLsXMHKZixENmzSDQ6Dvngw2x15g5ZLwigpyljUJ3zgRT8MHKYbYX2d%2FiyHJFvI0h1LWlO%2FXR%2BmMMLdY7ua6L8IPe8tsFppirBu6QHNSug1hMWUw2%2F%2FbnwY6ngEhoufR5Pk%2BrETTG071O%2F3z1vjMtq%2BXd6hf3GdMN3ZzQ2LLSDqBEpugtY4aknRGko0RTSbgA8VUHFZeAzxYmkRImTo207EmzeG7XM4fY28fEZT31sUV3GnkzX43TYPIqAeN6RAH4oc66Or4smlM802FS94IORKwm31TBuyi1vAxJ0QmuYnoBMLZbjFwz0dHsCwvOtsWXOyECFPooQDngg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3H2KTGZIA/20230223/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230223T060918Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=41317dda76635b37eef4f2204efa6a458a1e73552e3a9f0058ec0716cc32a080)

We using engine "Autodesk.Autocad+24_1"

We are not sure how to fix this issue, please suggest do we need to change to another engine or what coulod be the solution of it.

Comment: The report url is expired , can you share the log again ?

Comment: And also, kindly share the drawing with us.